# How to set custom service implementation in Retrofit2?

Tags: java, kotlin, retrofit2

Let's assume I have some api:

```
interface SomeApi {

    @GET("api/some")
    suspend fun getSome(): List<SomeDto>
}
```

And its custom implementation:

```
class SomeApiImpl : SomeApi {
    override suspend fun getSome(): List<SomeDto> {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Is it possible to config retrofit in such a way that instead of creating proxy implementation of SomeApi it will use SomeApiImpl?
Thanks!

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this would mean writing a [CallAdapter](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/CallAdapter.html), but I can't be sure this is really what you'd want. Can I ask why you want to do this? maybe there's another way to achieve your goal. If it's because of coroutines, retrofit already supports them using [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter) for example

Comment: Well, sometimes I do want to make http call and sometimes I don't. The case I have:
there is some service and want to expose it's api via retrofit (interfaces like SomeApi in the question above). In this case clients will have to make http call to get data. Also I'd like to use this api in service itself. In that case I'd like to avoid making network calls.

Comment: Sounds to me that you have a case for a [Repository Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-design)? You can have a repository that receive an implementation of the service that doesn't make http calls and the retrofit created api instance, which will make the calls. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)